# Add a sprite on circumference of a circle

Tags: android, c++, geometry, cocos2d-x

I want to randomly generate sprites on circumference of circle , but even after research of several hours , I couldn't come up with any solution.
That's what I can made till now

[image]

I've used this formula for it :

```
Sprite * pin = Sprite::create("pin.png");
pin->setPosition(Vec2((_circle->getContentSize().width/2)*(0.7/3), _circle->getContentSize().height*0.7));

Sprite * pin2 = Sprite::create("pin.png");
pin2->setPosition(Vec2((_circle->getContentSize().width/2)*(0.6/3), _circle->getContentSize().height*0.6));

Sprite * pin3 = Sprite::create("pin.png");
pin3->setPosition(Vec2((_circle->getContentSize().width/2)*(0.8/3), _circle->getContentSize().height*0.8));

Sprite * pin4 = Sprite::create("pin.png");
pin4->setPosition(Vec2((_circle->getContentSize().width/2)*(0.9/3), _circle->getContentSize().height*0.9));

Sprite * pin5 = Sprite::create("pin.png");
pin5->setPosition(Vec2((_circle->getContentSize().width/2)*(1/3), _circle->getContentSize().height));

_circle->addChild(pin);
_circle->addChild(pin2);
_circle->addChild(pin3);
_circle->addChild(pin4);
_circle->addChild(pin5);
```

But I want something like that(with correct angle which I couldn't do in sample image)

[image]

Please suggest some precise solution for it. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basic trig stuff -- `sin` and `cos` are your friends.

Example:

```
const float circle_x = ...;
const float circle_y = ...;
const float circle_radius = ...;
const float angle = ...;
const float x = cos(angle)*circle_radius + circle_x;
const float y = sin(angle)*circle_radius + circle_y;

// Draw stuff at (x, y).
```

Answer (score 1):

First, it's "circumference" not "circumstance" (that will help with your searches)

Second, you are using the size of the image, not the circle inside the image.

Third, you will need to use basic trigonometry for the solution. Determining points on a circle require the use of `sin` and `cos` functions. After you find the center of the circle and it's radius, these should be easy to calculate with just a little bit of research.